# How to extend chrome memory profiler to show it in different UI?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I want to extend chrome memory profiler for my website. Basically I want to use chrome dev tools to take snapshot for my website which will have different data like memory used , time to load , CPU utilization , etc and show it in a different UI format. I have searched for extending chrome but what I see from their documentation is that I can only extend the debugger not the profiler. Also will be more than happy if there is any library to do such profiling and produces the result in some format that I can plot. I need some help guys just to kick start.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably CSI might help you http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~cs234313/Websites/S11/07/site/manuals/FinalPresentation.pdf

also you can use window.performance.memory object for measuring memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for replying...I have seen all of these after posting the question. I am trying to use this.